# No Output From Entity in ModelSim Simulator - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have written a simple entity in VHDL to blink an LED and am trying to simulate it in ModelSim but am getting no transitions on the output.

Here is my HDL file for the `LED_Blink` entity:

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity LED_Blink is

generic (
    g_SYSTEM_CLOCK_PERIOD   : in time := 10 ns; -- 100 MHz clock period
    g_LED_ON_TIME           : in time := 1 sec
);

port(
    system_clock    : in Std_logic; 
    reset_fpga_L    : in Std_logic;

    led_out         : out Std_logic
);
end entity LED_Blink;

architecture RTL of LED_Blink is
    signal led_state : Std_logic;
    constant COUNTER_RELOAD_VAL : natural := g_LED_ON_TIME/g_SYSTEM_CLOCK_PERIOD;
begin
    process(reset_fpga_L, system_clock)
        variable counter : natural range 0 to COUNTER_RELOAD_VAL := COUNTER_RELOAD_VAL;
    begin
        if reset_fpga_L = '0' then
            counter := COUNTER_RELOAD_VAL;
            led_state <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(system_clock) then
            if counter = 0 then
                led_state <= not led_state;
                counter := COUNTER_RELOAD_VAL;
            else
                counter := counter - 1;
            end if;            
        end if;

        led_out <= led_state;
    end process;
end architecture RTL;
```

And here is my test-bench:

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity LED_Blink_TB is
end entity LED_Blink_TB;

architecture RTL of LED_Blink_TB is

    signal reset_fpga_L : Std_logic := '0';
    signal system_clock : Std_logic := '0';

    signal led_out      : Std_logic := '0';

begin

    G1: entity work.LED_Blink(RTL) port map(reset_fpga_L, system_clock, led_out);

    CLK: process
    begin
        while now <= 5 sec loop
            system_clock <= not system_clock;
            wait for 5 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process CLK;

    STIM: process
    begin
        reset_fpga_L <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        reset_fpga_L <= '1';
        wait for 4 sec;
        reset_fpga_L <= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        reset_fpga_L <= '1';
        wait;
    end process STIM;

end architecture RTL;
```

I can't figure out why I'm not seeing any transitions on `led_out` when I run my test-bench in the simulator. I've taken care to add the waves for `system_clock`, `reset_fpga_L`, and `led_out` to the trace view. Do you see anything in my code that might be an issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only issue I can see is that 1 second is a helluva lot of simulation time ... I'd set LED_ON_TIME to 1 ms or even 10 us in the generic map in the entity instantiation in the testbench.

Comment: Just gave that a try with the same result

Comment: With a slightly different [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7GHF.jpg) with generics set to a 100 ms clock period and 500 ms led_on you get this [waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piVbt.png). How much effort to simulate is based on how many transitions.

Comment: You'll also notice the half clock delay on led_out because it's in a process sensitive to the clock instead of a concurrent signal assignment or in a separate process.

Comment: @user1155120: Your testbench alerted me to an issue in my testbench in which my port map had `system_clock` and `reset_fpga_L` swapped. Please submit an answer to this effect so that I may award you the credit for finding this issue. Proof that the devil is indeed in the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second form of the testbench can be used make generation of inputs to LED_Blink depend on the values supplied as generics:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity led_blink_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of led_blink_tb is
    constant CLK_PERIOD:    time := 100 ms;
    constant LED_ON:        time := 500 ms;
    signal clk:             std_logic := '0';
    signal reset_n:         std_logic;
    signal led:             std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.led_blink
        generic map ( CLK_PERIOD, LED_ON)
        port map (
            system_clock => clk,
            reset_fpga_l => reset_n,
            led_out => led
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 2.5 sec then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        reset_n <= '0';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD * 2;
        reset_n <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The idea, both the testbench and the model depend on constants supplied as generics making changing the parameters require less work.

Also note the association list in the port map uses named association.

If we take a look at the original testbench port map:

```
G1: entity work.LED_Blink(RTL) port map(reset_fpga_L, system_clock, led_out);
```

We see that the first positional association to the formal system_clock is associated with the actual reset_fpga_L while the second positional association representing formal reset_fpga_L is associated with the actual system_clock.

The two actual associations are in reversed order.